# Unable to create a admin user in Windows VM using powershell command via Terraform

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, terraform

I want to spin up Windows VM and then using Ansible deploy a web application. I am able to spin-up a Windows VM. But unable to create a new admin user in the VM which is required for Anisble to deploy the playbook. Below is the code snippet I am using to create a new User in the VM.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "iis-windows-vm" {
.......
.......
.......

 settings = <<SETTINGS
   {
"commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted New-LocalUser \"user_name\" -AccountNeverExpires:$true -Password ( ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 'Password') -FullName \"user_name\" -PasswordNeverExpires:$true | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group \"Administrators\" -Member \"user_name\""
   }
 SETTINGS
 }
}
```

I am stuck in this phase for more than a day now. Request you guys to assist me on this and let me know where I am going wrong.

**UPDATE:** I removed `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group \"Administrators\" -Member \"user_name\""` from `commandToExecute` and now the user is getting created. Any idea what is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Since your command is enclosed in `"..."` overall, you must _escape_ `"` instances that are _embedded_ in the command (_presumably_ as `\"`). Alternatively, use embedded `'...'`-quoting (already partially employed in your command), or, in some cases, such the `-Member` parameter you don't need embedded quoting at all.

Comment: As “setttings” is a json string, you might find it easier to use terraform’s ```jsonencode``` function (https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) with a map instead of the ```<<SETTINGS``` fences and free text. That would give you better syntax highlighting in your editor, and would help identify the quote escaping issue @mklement0 pointed out. See the link for an example…

Comment: @mklement0..Thank you for pointing out the escaping issue. I have the marked the escape " in the code but while copying the code here it was missed.

Comment: @mclayton..I was not aware of the jsonecode. Thank you for letting me know. Also can we run multiple commands in the same "commandToExecute" or what is another to option to run multiple commands ?